# Override DNS lookup using mockito during junit java test

Tags: junit, dns, mockito, powermock, powermockito

Is it possible to override a single DNS lookup in the java jvm?

I am running a junit test in java. The test makes a connection to an external server host1. Instead, I want the jvm to contact localhost when it tries to contact host1.

The test succeeds if /etc/hosts file contains:

```
127.0.0.1 host1
```

I am wondering if it can be done without modifying the hosts file.

We are using java 8. The junit test uses mockito & powermock libraries. It will run on Mac OS Mojave & CentOS (some container in some kubernetes pod on gcp/aws).

Thanks for reading.

Comment: I have the same question, I'm developping a multi hostname API and needs it to respond  differently upon the host used in incoming http request. 
If you're trying to mock/redirect calls to an external service, you could rewrite code to use configuration and mock the configuration or use different properties for the test environment.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look at *poisoning* your user environment instead of the system `/etc/hosts` by tricking the system to load another `/etc/hosts`. See this for a Linux solution: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/57459/how-can-i-override-the-etc-hosts-file-at-user-level